# image does not load, 404

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzh3f.png)The image file is not loaded and results in 404, while viewing from browser

I am using AWS and running a docker container, the base image being ubuntu and apache2 is installed on it. I have a image folder and index.html in var/www/html, after containerising the code, the image is not shown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Intellipaat </title>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('images/github3.jpg'); background-size: 100%">
<img src="images/github3.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<h2 ALIGN=CENTER>Hello world!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The github.3 jpg must be loaded

Comment: What does this have to do with Kubernates and docker? If the image "doesn't load" then it isn't where you think it is. I'm not sure what else anyone can say here?

Comment: The question is, the same code runs fine in docker and I can see the image when i point to AWS instance, but when the same containerised image is delpoyed in kubernetes cluster the jpg is not loaded

Comment: So what does your `Dockerfile` look like? Where is this image? etc. etc.

Comment: FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apache2
ADD index.html /var/www/html
ADD images /var/www/html
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 83

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant information. Please avoid adding details in comments

Answer (score -1):

Try without the slash:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Intellipaat </title>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('images/github3.jpg'); background-size: 100%">
<img src="images/github3.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<h2 ALIGN=CENTER>Hello world!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a pretty random guess